# Unity 3D: Should I make an extensive script or multiple smaller ones for in game items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I'm trying to create a attatchment system for a 2D platform/shooter game, the weapon system is working great but I want to implement some attachments, diferent barrels, magazines even ammo types.

For the simpler ones that just modify a stat I was thinking of just creating a class or even a struct with all the possible stats (damage, recoil, spread etc) and just setting them to the appropiate values (+1, -5, 0 if it doesn't use it). However, there are some ideas that might require a separate method/function, like shooting different bullets.

My main question is would it be more effective/efficient to just make smaller scripts for the edge cases and a main one for the simple stat changers. Or should I just overload a main script/class with methods for all the possible attachments?

There aren't that many "special" attachments, but i'd like to make a system that expandable if possible.

Im not an expert programmer (I just learned about enums a couple days ago!) so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question. You should **ABSOLUTELY**, you **MUST** make many small components.  Enjoy!

Comment: Yup smaller, modular, decoupled component system is where unity shines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Unity's ScriptableObject class to create an abstract class then inherit from that abstract class to create more spesific classes and abstract classes.

Then I would create my attachments etc. in unity editor and modify whatever value I want from it.

An example armor piece would inherit the following ArmorItem class and use the ApplyEffect method to make the player bigger to show that you can make any type of modification.

ItemBase class

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class ItemBase: ScriptableObject
{
    public string ItemName;
    
    public abstract void ApplyEffect();//override this method for any edge case items
}
```

ArmorItem

```
public abstract class ArmorItem: ItemBase
{
    public float Armor;//use this however you want
}
```

EdgeCaseArmor

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Items/Armor/EdgeCaseArmor")]
public class EdgeCaseArmor: ArmorItem
{
    public override void ApplyEffect()
    {
        //find player and make it bigger
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.localScale *= 1.5f;
    }
}
```

Obviously you will need to load items and somehow call ApplyEffect. You can do it at the start of the game by adding this to a start method.

```
var item = Resources.Load("path to your scriptable object that inherits ItemBase") as ItemBase;
item.Activate();
```

How you load the items and call them is up to you. You will need to save your scriptable objects in Assets>Resources folder(create one if you haven't created one already).

You can also make multiple armors with different names, armor values etc. like this.

Note that if you want to have an armor with no special effect you will need to make ArmorItem a normal class or make a NormalArmor class that inherits ArmorItem. Just leave the ApplyEffect function empty if you don't want any special effects.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, this was exactly what I was looking for.

My final question is how does inheriting from ScriptableObject differ from just using a regular class.

From what I have tested/seen its mainly being able to set variables throught the inspector, which is enough for me tbh

Comment: you can easily create multiple versions(or instances) of a scriptable object in editor instead of using prefabs or some other method. Moreover they provide a nice formatted environment to set your values. Check [this](https://youtu.be/aPXvoWVabPY) video from brackeys for more details.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a fairly general question so keep in mind that you may get several varying opinion-related answers.*

With that said, the biggest suggestion that I would give is to look into `Inheritance`. Using a series of `interfaces` and `classes` to more refine the base concept of "item modifications".

For instance, I would create an `interface`:

```
interface IItemModification
{
   void Apply();
}
```

Any more refined modification `class` or `interface` would implement (in the case of a `class`) or inherit (in the case of another `interface`)  this `interface`.

In this example we will just create a base class that implements that interface:

```
public class ItemModification : IItemModification
{
   public void Apply()
   {
      // Logic to apply modifications to the item.
   }
}
```

In the case above, you now have a very basic `class` that represents an item modification which contains the implementation of the `interface`.

Next you might want to go into further detail, perhaps by creating item type implementations:

```
public class WeaponItemModification : ItemModification
{
   public ArmorItemModification(StatModifiers modifiers, AttackType attackType)
   {
      this.Modifiers = modifiers;
      this.Attack= attackType;
   }
   public AttackType Attack
   {
      get; set;
   }

   public StatModification Modifiers { get; set; }
}

public class ArmorItemModification : ItemModification
{
   public ArmorItemModification(StatModifiers modifiers, DefenseType defenseType)
   {
      this.Modifiers = modifiers;
      this.Defense = defenseType;
   }
   public DefenseType Defense
   {
      get; set;
   }

   public StatModification Modifiers { get; set; }
}
```

Of course a logical progression of that would be more specific item types:

```
public class VestModification : ArmorItemModification
{
   public VestModification(StatModification modifiers, DefenseType defenseType, AreaProtectionType areaProtectionType)
   {
      this.Modifiers = modifiers;
      this.Defense = defenseType;
      this.AreaProtection = areaProtectionType;
   }
   public AreaProtectionType AreaProtection
   {
      get; set;
   }
}
```

These are just some basic examples to point you in the right direction. I would suggest reading up on inheritance concepts to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Note too that for the OP, simply subclassing may be a thing worth learning about.  It's tricky working with Unity, which is ECS.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response, my question is vague, but the answer does point me in the right direction.

To get things straight you are basically sugesting using separate classes (in separate scripts maybe?) to represent individual special items or item types and using inheritance and interfaces to make a framework that defines what an item is at its core.

Im not to familiarized with the way inheritance works in c# but ill take a look at it.

And from what I understand, an interface is mostly to avoid assuptions / making sure all classes have the same functios as the interface.

Comment: Basically, yes. An interface is a contract that specifies how a class exposes its members. If a class implements an interface, the internal workings may be very different, but the accessible members are guaranteed to be available.